# L’uso di bello come rafforzativo

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Uno degli usi dell’aggettivo bello è quello di [rafforzare un sostantivo o un aggettivo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bello/), praticamente con il significato di tanto o molto.

In frasi  come:

> Sono stato un bello stupido a crederci. 
>   Mi faccia un cappuccino bello caldo. 
>   Ho guadagnato una bella somma.
>   Un bel pezzo di strada.

Il [dizionario etimologico](https://www.etimo.it/?term=bello) non chiarisce l’origine di questo uso.

Qualcuno sa dirmi quale è  l’origine di questo significato? Ha forse a che fare con il latino?

Comment: Sono abbastanza sicuro che il rafforzativo "bello" sia di origine napoletana, in quanto in napoletano è molto più diffuso nelle espressioni d'uso comune (qualcosa che è buono di gusto oppure che funziona bene viene etichettato come "bello"). Come spesso accade, è probabile che questo modo di dire provenga da una contaminazione - fraintendimento di qualche parola spagnola o francese ma non riesco a intuire quale

Comment: È molto presente anche nel dialetto parmigiano, ma credo che in generale non ci sia bisogno di una etimologia molto articolata. È un aggettivo con un senso positivo, quindi il "rafforzamento" è molto intuitivo, immediato.

Answer (score 2):

Secondo il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*, che riporta le [prime attestazioni delle diverse accezioni](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000007.jpg) di ogni termine,  i primi usi di ["bello"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI02/00000158.jpg) per indicare "molto, abbondante, grande, grosso, notevole, ecc." come qualifica di un sostantivo risalgono al Trecento. Su questa fonte ne troviamo questi esempi del *Decameron* di Boccaccio e dei *Ricordi* di Giovanni di Pagolo Morelli:

> *Boccaccio, Dec., 2-7* (196): Fece una sera, per modo di solenne festa, una bella cena. *Idem, Dec., 8-2* (239): Per bella paura entro, col mosto e con le castagne calde si rappattumò con lui. *G. Morelli*, 445: Per bella paura... gittò le bandiere del Comune in terra giù ne' fossi.

Invece, l'uso di "bello" seguito immediatamente da un aggettivo per "sottolineare il valore dell'aggettivo" a cui accompagna è molto più recente: questo dizionario riporta come prima attestazione questa citazione dai *Cento racconti popolari lucchesi* di Idelfonso Nieri, pubblicati nel 1906:

> *Nieri*, 245: Una volta un uomo, là sulla fine di Maggio, aveva menato il miccio a pascere, e l'aveva lasciato bello libero, perché si scialasse meglio.

Tuttavia, la prima attestazione dell'espressione "bello e" o "bell' e" seguita da un aggettivo o da un participio (o da un avverbio e più raramente anche da un infinito o un sostantivo) risale all'inizio del Trecento:

> *Fra Giordano*, 3-152: Noi avemo l'uovo bello e mondo, e la gallina bella e cotta, e non avemo se non a mangiare.
> *Boccaccio, Dec., 8-3* (243): Chi facesse le macine belle e fatte legare in anella, prima che elle si forassero.

Questi usi di "bello" non sembrano avere a che vedere col latino: secondo lo [stesso dizionario](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI02/00000160.jpg) l'aggettivo latino *bellus* proveniva

> dal linguaggio affettivo e familiare come dimin. di *bonus* (cfr. le forme arcaiche attestate *duenos* e *duomus*), con la vocale che si continua nell'avv. *bene*: **benülus* da **duenolos*.

Answer (score -1):

Penso dipenda dal fatto che il "bello" in tempi passati era assimilato alla dimensione. In tempi di "magrezza" e povertà, qualcosa di pieno, robusto, grande veniva inteso come "bello". Si pensi all'espressione "un bel piatto di pasta" o simili.